# библиотека PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Подскажите как сделать дозапись в ексель файл с помощью PHP Excel
Т.е. есть данные в текущем .xls файле, после чего нужно сделать новые записи + старые записи

Само сохранение происходит так

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'save_excel/excel_temp/leads_'.date('d.m.Y').'.xls')
```

Answer (score 0):

PHPExcel устарел, используйте актуальную библиотеку

https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/#welcome-to-phpspreadsheets-documentation

В документации есть пример по вашему вопросу.

Comment: Все написано на PHP excel. Необходимо решение на PHP excel – Игорь Роганов 26 секунд назад   Править    Удалить

Comment: @ИгорьРоганов посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416934/adding-a-new-row-with-phpexcel решение как полагаю уже есть.